# How to disable Dark Mode in Google Chrome on macOS Mojave?

Tags: google-chrome, mojave, dark-mode

I have configured my installation of macOS Mojave to Dark Mode, because I prefer it over the Light Mode for some reasons.

The thing is that with the recent update, Google Chrome also automatically adopts the Dark Mode. I can't even see sometimes in which tab I'm in since it does not let me see clearly.

[image]

I have researched and found official Google Chrome Themes [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes?hl=en), but they seem to apply above the default Dark theme, which is not looking well.

If I disable Dark Mode in systemwide, I can see Google Chrome in Light Mode as usual, but I would love to see Google Chrome in Light Mode while using macOS Mojave in Dark Mode.

Is there a way to configure the desired behaviour.

Comment: @user3439894 Noted.